# Stop execution of php script when called from iframe

Tags: php, security, iframe, x-frame-options, clickjacking

I have this page logout.php on my website which is causing the users to logout when called from iframe like:

```
<iframe src="http://www.aaa.com/logout.php" style="width:0; height:0; border:0; border:none"></iframe>
```

I have already put the following header at top of my php page logout.php and it is showing error in browser console on opening the page containing the iframe but it does not seem to stop the execution of the remaining code in logout.php on server and the user ends up getting logged out:

```
header('X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN');
```

What is the correct way to solve this issue?

Comment: GET requests should be [idempotent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Idempotent). You can change your logout page to only function on POST requests.